# Why do not reconnect server while I changed file on watch mode in nestJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

In my nestJs project When I run "nest start --watch" it's running fine. But when I changed something it's reload  and does not connect to server. Show "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000". How do I fix it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still suffering from this phenomenon.
I too encountered this phenomenon when running nest app on wsl2.
Adding `app.enableShutdownHooks()` to main.ts worked for me.

src/main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });

> app.enableShutdownHooks();

  await app.listen(Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```